# Date issue, string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, date, flask, typeerror

I am trying to run a project which I did not code my self and I am facing this issue when running the code,
I have holidays.json collection: [image]

and I have this part of code to parse holidays from this json:

```
def parse_holidays():
    holidays = db.holidays.find_one({}, {'_id': 0})
    for holiday in holidays:
        holidays[holiday]['date'] = datetime.strptime(holidays[holiday]['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date()

    return holidays
```

and I am getting the error:

```
        holidays[holiday]['date'] = datetime.strptime(holidays[holiday]['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date() TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any idea how to solve it?
the code is in python, using Flask.

Comment: What is the value of `holidays[holiday]`?

Comment: @jarmod The value of holidays[holiday] is one holiday from the holidays json file.. so for example "pesah_evening": {
"date": "27/3/2021",
"taoz": "friday_holiday_evening"
},

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. Did you debug this or print the value of `holidays[holiday]` to verify it? Add this to your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
holidays[holiday]['date']
```

holiday value is an object but you are using it as a string to reach a variable.
Instead of the way above, you should use the method below.

```
holiday['date'] = datetime.strptime(holiday['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

Comment: After changing I am still getting: "TypeError: string indices must be integers"
any idea why?

Comment: Can you send your complete structure of the holidays.json file? Is it like [{objects}] or {objects}?

Answer (score 0):

`db.holidays.find_one()` returns a single document of your database.
Therefore `holidays` is a dictionary, e.g `{ "date": "27/3/2021", "taoz": "friday_holiday_evening" }`.

When you loop over it, you're looping over its keys and thus `holiday` takes the values "date" and "taoz". As a consequence `holidays[holiday]` is looping over the dictionary values, which are all strings.

`holidays[holiday]['date']` is therefore a nonsense, since you're trying to index a string (`holidays[holiday]`) using a non-numeric index (`'date'`).

In order to make your code working, try to replace `find_one` with `find`.